# MySQL remote connection takes more than 3 minutes to display result

Tags: mysql, mariadb, centos7

I am trying to connect from a local server to my remote server with `mysql` command...

Result after long delay:

```
[root@local ~] mysqlshow -u test -p*** -h XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading authorization packet', system error: 0
```

(The connection is done through my second remote server without any error or delay)

### Update 1

Retry connecting from local server after add `connect_timeout=500` to the remote server's **/etc/my.cnf**:

```
[root@local ~] time mysqlshow -u test -p*** -h XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
+---------------------+
|      Databases      |
+---------------------+
| foo                 |
| bar                 |
+---------------------+

real    3m21.174s  <======== (3m!)
user    0m0.004s
sys     0m0.015s
```

Successful connection but with more than 3 minutes delay to display the result!

The interesting thing is that when the connection is established, other mysql requests (e.g. `mysql> SELECT`) take effect immediately!

### Update 2

Same result after add `skip-host-cache` and `skip-name-resolve` to remote server's **/etc/my.cnf**...

### Update 3

Same request through my second remote server: *(Everything seems good)*

```
[root@remote2 ~] time mysqlshow -u test -p*** -h XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
+---------------------+
|      Databases      |
+---------------------+
| foo                 |
| bar                 |
+---------------------+

real    0m0.016s  <======== (0.016s)
user    0m0.007s
sys     0m0.002s
```

### Update 4

Check MySQL Connection from local server with `telnet`: *(Everything seems good!)*

```
[root@local ~] time echo X | telnet -e X XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX 3306
Telnet escape character is 'X'.
Trying XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX...
Connected to XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX.
Escape character is 'X'.

telnet> Connection closed.

real    0m0.136s  <======== (0.136s)
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.005s
```

### Update 5

Try to connect through PHP `mysqli` from local server:

```
<?php
$servername = "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX";
$username = "test";
$password = "***";
$dbname = "dbname";

$conn = new mysqli( $servername, $username, $password, $dbname );

if( $conn->connect_error ) {
    die($conn->connect_error);
}
?>
```

Result:

```
Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/2002): Permission denied in /var/www/html/test.php on line 7
Permission denied
```

(The PHP mysqli connection is done through the second remote server without any error or delay)

### Update 6

Retry with disabled `SELinux` on the local server solves the PHP connection error but the connection still takes more than 3 minutes!

When the connection is established, other requests (e.g. `SELECT`) take effect immediately.

### Update 7

After trying to connect from local server, On the server's phpMyAdmin (or `mysqladmin proc` command), new connection added with unauthenticated user...

[image]

### Update 8

Connection try through `XAMPP` on windows (from different PC and network) to the remote server:

Same result (connecting with unauthenticated user and more than 3 minutes delay to display results) ...

I'm about to go crazy!!

Comment: When you say ssh. Do you mean you are going through a ssh tunnel?

Comment: @Jason K: The question was edited. I meant trying through the command...